# How to swipe pdf pages horizontally in android using MuPDF library

Tags: horizontal-scrolling, mupdf

I have built mupdf from source following these steps http://www.mupdf.com/docs/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android. I have integrated it in my app and it is working fine.
But in that page is scroll vertically but i want to scroll horizontally. Please help me is it possible or not And if possible give me hint or if any other solution Thanks.

Comment: This project has a horizontally scrolling viewer using mupdf: https://github.com/libreliodev/android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MuPDFPageView instead of the MuPDFReaderView and manage the horizontal scroll manually.

Answer (score 1):

in `ReaderView.class` from

> android mupdf library

, you must `HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING="false"`

Answer (score 1):

Good news that I created new repo implement method called

`swipeHorizontal(boolean isHorizontal)` till create Nuget

https://github.com/minaairsupport/MuPDF_Xamarin