# How to swipe pdf pages vertically in Xamarin.android using MuPDF library

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

How to swipe pdf pages vertically in Xamarin.android using [MuPDF library](https://mupdf.com/) ?

Comment: Did you try to use this plugin in your project ?https://github.com/minaairsupport/MuPDF_Xamarin this plugin achieved swipeHorizontal(boolean isHorizontal) to change orentation of swiping between horizontal and vertica

Comment: I have checked there is no such flag for orientation.

Comment: You could try to change the horizontal values to vertical ( change all width related calculations to height ). Change onLayout() &onFling() like this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33333069/mupdf-android-library-vertical-scroll